# using case_when inside dplyr's mutate to create a new column in dataframe based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to create a new column in my data frame that is based off another column having a certain unique value. I have successfully done this by using the case_when argument inside a mutate. However, I would like to use a str_detect because I have a great deal of data and I don't want to have to type every single unique value because most are the same just different by the last few numbers in the string.. I keep getting errors when I try to use str_detect inside of the case_when.. does any one know how I can achieve this?

**dput of data:**

```
 dput(head(HUC_wq_summary,10))
structure(list(locid = c("21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", 
"21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", 
"21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", 
"21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380"), parameter = c("Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", 
"Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", "Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", 
"Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", "Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", 
"Ammonia-nitrogen as N", "Ammonia-nitrogen as N", "Ammonia-nitrogen as N", 
"Ammonia-nitrogen as N", "Barometric pressure"), ActivityStartDate = structure(c(13902, 
13986, 14075, 14179, 14271, 13902, 13986, 14075, 14271, 13902
), class = "Date"), ActivityEndDate = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Samples = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), MinValue = c(26, 44, 40, 
28, 25, 0.12, 0.01, 0.05, 0.13, 760), MaxValue = c(26, 44, 40, 
28, 25, 0.12, 0.01, 0.05, 0.13, 760), Average = c(26, 44, 40, 
28, 25, 0.12, 0.01, 0.05, 0.13, 760), HUC14 = c("HUC02040201040070", 
"HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", 
"HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", 
"HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070"
), Trib = c("HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", 
"HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", 
"HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", "HUC02040201040070", 
"HUC02040201040070")), .Names = c("locid", "parameter", "ActivityStartDate", 
"ActivityEndDate", "Samples", "MinValue", "MaxValue", "Average", 
"HUC14", "Trib"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("locid", "parameter", 
"ActivityStartDate"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), group_sizes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    locid = c("21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", 
    "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", 
    "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", "21NJDEP1-01464380", 
    "21NJDEP1-01464380"), parameter = c("Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", 
    "Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", "Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", 
    "Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", "Alkalinity, Carbonate as CaCO3", 
    "Ammonia-nitrogen as N", "Ammonia-nitrogen as N", "Ammonia-nitrogen as N", 
    "Ammonia-nitrogen as N", "Barometric pressure"), ActivityStartDate = structure(c(13902, 
    13986, 14075, 14179, 14271, 13902, 13986, 14075, 14271, 13902
    ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("locid", 
"parameter", "ActivityStartDate"), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("locid", 
"parameter", "ActivityStartDate")))
```

**Code:**

```
HUC_wq_summary<-HUC_wq_summary%>%
   mutate(Trib=case_when(HUC14 == "HUC02040202100060" ~ "Pennsauken",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202100050" ~ "Pennsauken",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202100020" ~ "Pennsauken",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202100030" ~ "Pennsauken",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202100040" ~ "Pennsauken",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202100010" ~ "Pennsauken",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202150010" ~ "Raccoon",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202150060" ~ "Raccoon",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202150020" ~ "Raccoon",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202150040" ~ "Raccoon",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202150050" ~ "Raccoon",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202150030" ~ "Raccoon",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202080040"~ "Rancocas",
                         HUC14 == "HUC02040202080030"~ "Rancocas",
                         HUC14 == str_detect(HUC14,"HUC020402020600"~ "Rancocas"),TRUE ~ HUC14))
```

As you can see most of the HUC14 strings are the same for each just different by a few numbers.

Comment: So what are you trying to use for your `str_detect`? It seems like this might actually be a regex question more than a `case_when` question, since you already have a `case_when` call setup

Comment: @camille edited to show what I have tried for str_detect

Comment: you just have the syntax wrong: `str_detect(HUC14,"HUC020402020600") ~ "Rancocas"`

Comment: `HUC14 == str_detect(HUC14,"HUC020402020600"~ "Rancocas")` doesn't make sense. `str_detect` returns a true/false, so unless `HUC14` might contain a logical value, you wouldn't be comparing those two things. You also have the `~` part of that line inside of you `str_detect`

Comment: It would be helpful if you removed the columns of data that we don't need to address this problem, to keep the example *minimal*.

Comment: Also, the data you posted only contains one value of `HUC14`, and it isn't one that you handle in your example code, so this currently isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
HUC_wq_summary <- HUC_wq_summary %>%          
         mutate(Trib=case_when(str_detect(HUC14,".*000[1-6]0") ~ "Pennsauken", #Search for 000 followed by a digit from 1-6 followed by 0
                               str_detect(HUC14,".*500[1-6]0" ) ~ "Raccoon", 
                               str_detect(HUC14,".*800[34]0" ) ~ "Rancocas",  #Search for 800 followed by 3 or 4 followed by 0
                               TRUE ~ HUC14))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
HUC_wq_summary$Trib <- cut(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", HUC_wq_summary$HUC14)), #keep only digits
    c(02040201040030, 02040202080030, 02040202100010, 02040202150010, Inf), #create intervals
    c("BlacksCrosswicks", "Rancocas", "Raccoon", "Pennsauken"), #define labels
    include.lowest = T) # close intervals on the left rather than on the right
```

Basically, you only keep the digits of the `HUC14` variable and make it numeric. Then you create the intervals, the first from `02040201040030` to `02040202080030`, which is labelled `"BlacksCrosswicks"`, etc.

Comment: I Don't understand how this solves my problem? Can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!